# Is there anyway to consume food faster?

Tags: stardew-valley

I just started exploring the mines, where I use up my energy fairly quick.  Currently, I have a stockpile of salmonberries that I've been eating to get my energy back.  However, it's slow going.  Each time I go to eat one, the dialogue box pops up asking me if I am really sure that I want to eat it, and then the animation of my character consuming it begins (which is also long).

Is there a way to consume items faster?  It rather annoying having to say yes each time to eat a berry and watching the animation.  At the very least, I'd like to make the pop up go away.  I'm playing on Xbox One.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to skip or speed up the animation for consuming food or to bypass the confirmation popup.

Comment: Can confirm, answer is short but the to the point. You will always get this pop up box. It may be slow, but it really helps you out when you misclick something expensive.

Comment: Source? Experience with the game? This looks like the kind of post we would flag a new user for posting.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Sometimes, the answer is just yes or no. Extra info like I've added in my answer might be nice to have, but in the end it's extra info - not strictly necessary for the answer to be correct.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Is it really needed to add "From what I've seen" to every answer? I thought the assumption was that everyone spoke from experience.

Comment: Simply to add some credibility to the answer, rather than a simple statement. I try to post without assuming much of anything.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this in the current version.

The only way to alleviate the problem in-game is to keep a stockpile of food that restores more energy per use. Spicy Eel seems to be a fan-favorite due to its additional speed bonus, and it gives more than 4x the energy of salmonberries (115 vs 25 energy restored). It drops semi-reliably from the flying lizards in the dungeon. Alternatively, salad (113 energy, bought from Gus in the bar) is also very efficient, though it'll cost a bit of money to buy a stack.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion; I figured this as much but since I just started the game, I haven't made/come across any high energy foods just yet.

Comment: @TimmyJim I've recently gotten back into playing this game, and I'm actually using Hops as my go-to healing item. Takes a while to grow in the summer, but once it's matured it grows one Hops per plant per day. Each base quality Hops replenishes 45 energy, which is approximately 16% of starting energy levels. There are definitely better sources, but this is pretty cheap and very replenishable.

Answer (score 0):

On PC you can install the Auto-Eat mod.  Unfortunately this won't help you on the Xbox One.

> This mod is pretty simple:
>   Once you run out of Energy, you will automatically consume the cheapest food you have in your inventory, and you aren't punished with over-exertion the way you normally are.

http://www.nexusmods.com/stardewvalley/mods/643/?